# how i can format datetime in android?

Tags: java, android, time, formatting

i have a problem in datetime format.
i have two questions. first i have like this datetime 07/17/2014 and i want to convert this datetime like 17  august
and second question
i have two datetimes 07/17/2014 and 07/24/2014 and i try to check Difference there datetimes.i mean 24 - 17=7
i searched and  found some codes

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
mTimeText.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

but i don't know how i can solve my problems
if anyone knows solution please help me .thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you whant the year include you can use

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date(location.getTime())
```

If you want more control and don't include the year use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM").format(new Date(location.getTime())
```

Checkout http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html